# can I sync files for offline use using same path, without Windows Offline Files?

Tags: sync

I am currently using FreeFileSync, a by-donation software to sync any folders.  I previously used Sync Toy from Microsoft.  Previous to that, I used Microsoft's Offline Files feature in Windows.  I use Windows 11 Pro.

Problem 1: Microsoft Sync Center is unreliable.

Problem 2: Using synced files on local laptop has a different path from network files.

Problem 1 details: Microsoft's Offline Files / Sync Center never worked.  My laptop was connected to the LAN but could never see files.  Empty folders where files on the server should exist were just taunting ghosts of files only available "online", except that I *was* online.  Hundreds of posts on various fora tell that others have the same issue.  I have long since abandoned Microsoft's Sync Center.

Problem 2 details: FreeFileSync is the most reliable, thorough, and updated sync software that I've used.  When back on my LAN, I click, wait, and everything is synced.  However, the dozen or so local folders open must be closed, and the equivalent server folders must be opened, so that I can work "online" again, and everything is reflected as such on my website and for other users on the LAN.  I have also used Microsoft's Sync Toy which is almost as reliable.

Question: Is there sync software available that keeps the same path (i.e. \allan22\D\documents\teaching\private material\mathematics) while working offline?  That is, something that works similarly to Windows Sync Center?

This might seem like small potatoes to some, but it's a time waster for me.  Thank you for any comments! -Allan